# Apagar inputs depois automáticamente

Tags: html, ajax

Tenho este código para enviar dados por método POST, mas depois não limpa os inputs::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                            $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        } else {
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

Além deste exemplo já tentei alterando esta linha `$("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text` por:

```
$("#feedback_form")[0].reset('input').val(''); //clear text
```

por:

```
$("#feedback_form")[0].reset(); //clear text
```

por:

```
$('input').val(''); //clear text
```

por:

```
$('#feedback_form input').val(''); //clear text
```

mas nenhuma destas alternativas limpou os inputs.

Html e JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
        <div id="success_messages" class="hide">sucessso</div>
        <div id="error_message" class="hide">erro</div>
</form>

</section>
```

Comment: @dvd, Ainda não, faço var_dump ($.trim) para me assegurar que entra no if?

Comment: Sim, eu percebi que era esse if, mas fazendo esse var_dump, verifico se entra nesse if?

Comment: coloquei o alert a seguir ao if e não retornou o ok na página

Comment: Então não está entrando no IF, por isso não limpa os campos.

Comment: coloque um console.log(data) antes do IF e veja no console o que mostra como retorno do Ajax.

Comment: @dvd, não retorna nada no ajax

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78078/discussion-between-iniciante-and-dvd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema detectado foi que o `if` nunca é acessado porque o retorno esperado é um JSON (`dataType: "json",`) e não um `"true"`.

Precisa usar os *callbacks* do Ajax para verificar se o retorno foi um JSON válido ou não: `success` e `error` respectivamente. E para limpar os campos você usa o `complete` (irá limpar os campos em qualquer situação):

```
$(".btn_contact").click(function () { 

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "./inserir", 
        data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements. 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (data) 
        { 
            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message 
        }, 
        error: function(data){ 
            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message 
        }, 
        complete: function() 
        { 
            $('input', "#feedback_form").val(''); //clear text 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Troca essa linha:

```
$("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
```

Por essa, utilizando o `trigger()` do Jquery:

```
$("#feedback_form').trigger("reset");
```

Dá uma olhada aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form

Comment: Também não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Duas opçoes:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
$(this)[0].reset();
```

});

Ou pegue campo a campo:

```
document.getElementById('IdDocampo').value=''; // Limpa o campo
```

Exemplo:

```
 <form name="form">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('lastname').value=''; ">
</form>
```

USANDO SEU CÓDIGO:

```
    <section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form name="form" class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" id="bt" type="button">Registo</button>
        <div id="success_messages" class="hide">sucessso</div>
        <div id="error_message" class="hide">erro</div>
</form>

</section> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#bt").click(function () {
   document.getElementById('DescricaoProd').value=''; 

 document.getElementById('DescricaoUnid').value=''; 
});


</script>
```

Comment: Estranho, nenhuma das duas também funcionou

Comment: posta o html/js

Comment: já adicionei html e o `script` do js

Comment: continua sem funcionar

Comment: aqui vai. olha no console do navegador pra ver se da algum erro

Comment: Não retorna nenhum erro na consola

Comment: coloca um alert(9); depois de $("#bt").click(function () {
   document.getElementById('DescricaoProd').value=''; 

 document.getElementById('DescricaoUnid').value=''; 
});e clica..recarrega e clica veja se está disparando.

Comment: $("#bt").click(function () { alert(9);
   document.getElementById('DescricaoProd').value=''; 

 document.getElementById('DescricaoUnid').value=''; 
});

Comment: Não está a disparar, mantém os inputs preenchidos e na consola não retorna nada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78075/discussion-between-israel-zebulon-and-iniciante).

Answer (score 0):

Como os seus inputs são apenas do tipo **text**, tenta assim:

```
$('#myForm input[type=text]').val("");
```

Comment: também não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

**Provavelmente o seu script está antes do HTML.**

> Você tem duas opções:

1. Colocar o script antes da tag de fechamento BODY
2. Ou envolver ele na função `$(document).ready(function(){` daí você coloca em qualquer lugar do seu código fonte.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(".btn_contact").click(function () {

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "./inserir",
                   data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (data)
                   {
                       if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                           $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                           $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                       } else {
                           $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                       }
                   }
               });

      });
   });
   ```

**O proposito do `ready` é executar algo o mais rápido possível depois de carregar o documento, sem precisar esperar todo o conteúdo ser carregado.**

> @Iniciante, com certeza deve ter um caminhoneiro de greve dentro do seu script! Coloquei seu código nessa pagina e trabalha bem. Só troquei o url para apontar pro meu arquivo online. Veja seu código funcionando [**clicando aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/iniciante33.html)

3. Se nenhuma das opções acima funcionam, então seu  workbench deve tá bichado. **Reinicie-o!**

Comment: o meu script já tem esta linha $(document).ready(function(){, eu é que me esqueci de colocar na questão.

Comment: @Iniciante, com certeza deve ter um caminhoneiro de greve dentro do seu script! Coloquei seu código nessa pagina e trabalha bem. Só troquei o url para apontar pro meu arquivo online. Veja http://kithomepage.com/sos/iniciante33.html

Comment: vai ser mais um problema daqueles estranhos tipo workbench...só não funciona no meu...mas penso que o problema é não entrar no if

Comment: Não é problema do if não, postei seu código no meu servidor e funciona corretamente!